# Computing equations of motion for type IIB supergravity

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, differential-geometry, variational-principle, variational-calculus, supergravity

I'm doing some introductory calculations on the D3-brane solution of type IIB supergravity. I'm considering the theory with action

$$S_{\text{IIB}} = \frac{1}{8\pi G_{10}}\int d^{10}z\sqrt{g_{10}}\left(\frac{1}{2}R_{10} - \frac{1}{2\times 5!}F_{MNPQR}F^{MNPQR} - \frac{1}{2}\partial_M \phi \partial^M \phi\right).$$

I want to check that the following is a solution to the equations of motion:
\begin{align*}
    ds^2_{10} &= \frac{1}{\sqrt{H(y^a)}} \eta_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu + \sqrt{H(y^a)} \delta_{ab}dy^ady^b, \\
    F &= \frac{1}{2}(dA + *(dA)) \qquad \qquad A = \frac{1}{H(y^a)}dx^0 \wedge dx^1 \wedge dx^2 \wedge x^3 \\
    \phi &\equiv 0 \qquad \qquad \sum_{a=1}^6\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^a \partial y^a}H = 0.
\end{align*}

However, I am having some trouble with the computation. Finding the eom for the metric and for the scalar field are the 'usual' way of varying the action. However, I am confused on the $A$ part, as I am stuck with this Hodge star. If I am correct this guy is defined as $$*e^{a_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e^{a_p} = \frac{1}{q!}e^{b_1} \wedge \dots \wedge e^{b_q}\epsilon_{b_1\dots b_q} {}^{a_1\dots a_p}.$$

Comment: You can't assume that $F$ is self-dual to find equations of motion since $F \wedge \star F = F \wedge F = 0$ so the Maxwell action for a self-dual field vanishes. You need to assume that $F=dA$ in the action, then vary and find equations of motion. _AFTER THAT_ you impose $F = \star F$ as a constraint.

Comment: No, I'm not assuming $F$ is self-dual to find the equations of motion. I want to prove that this is a solution to the eom. So I want to derive the eom first. But from what I understand from your comment is that I just have to consider $F = dA$ in the action and just vary that with respect to $A$? Would you be able to show this also in an answer?

Comment: What would you like me to show exactly?

Comment: The eom for $A$. (and if you're really up for it, for the metric and the scalar field too, but those I'm confident that I can do)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The equations of motion for this system are rather easy to find. I am not going to work out any coefficients or normalization. You can work them out carefully.

1. The gauge field part of the action is
   $$
   S_{gauge} = \int F \wedge \star F , \qquad F = dA.
   $$
   Varying w.r.t. $A$
   $$
   \delta S_{gauge} = 2 \int d \delta A \wedge \star F = 2 \int \delta A \wedge d \star F
   $$
   where I integrated by parts *without* keeping track of the boundary terms. The equations of motion are therefore $d \star F = 0$. In index notation, this is $\nabla^M F_{MNPQR} = 0$.
2. The scalar part of the action is
   $$
   S_{scalar} = \int d \phi \wedge \star d \phi 
   $$
   Varying w.r.t. $\phi$
   $$
   S_{scalar} = 2 \int d \delta \phi \wedge \star d \phi = - 2 \int \delta \phi d \star d \phi .
   $$
   The equations of motion are therefore $d \star d \phi = 0$. In index notation, this is $\nabla^M \nabla_M \phi = 0$.
3. The metric part includes the whole action
   $$
   S_{grav} = \int \sqrt{-g} [ R + F^2 + ( \partial \phi )^2 ] 
   $$
   Varying w.r.t. $g$
   \begin{align}
   \delta S_{grav} &= \int \delta \sqrt{-g} [ R  + F^2 + ( \partial \phi )^2 ] + \int \sqrt{-g} \delta [ R + F^2 + ( \partial \phi )^2 ] \\
   &= \int\sqrt{-g}  ( - \frac{1}{2} g_{MN} \delta g^{MN} ) [ R  + F^2 + ( \partial \phi )^2 ] + \int \sqrt{-g} [ R_{MN}  + 2  F_{MP} F_N{}^P  +  \partial_M \phi \partial_N \phi ] \delta g^{MN} \\
   &= \int \sqrt{-g} [ G_{MN}  + 2 T_{MN}^{em} + T_{MN}^\phi ] \delta g^{MN}
   \end{align}
   where
   $$
   T_{MN}^{em} = F_{MP} F_N{}^P - \frac{1}{4} g_{MN} F^2 , \qquad T_{MN}^\phi = \partial_M \phi \partial_N \phi - \frac{1}{2} g_{MN}  ( \partial \phi )^2
   $$
   The equations are therefore
   $$
   G_{MN}  + 2 T_{MN}^{em} + T_{MN}^\phi = 0 . 
   $$

Comment: Perfect! My metric and scalar answers also match up with yours

Comment: Isn't it true that the normalization doesn't matter at all here?

Comment: Not for the scalar or the gauge field terms. It matters for Einsteins equations.